# Twilio introduces 5-second delay before playing mp3 files

Tags: twilio

We have built a simple proof of concept app using Twilio.  The app plays very short MP3 files upon demand.  We are consistently seeing a delay of about 5 seconds before the audio plays.  Our audio files have no delay/silence at the beginning.  Our files are very small.  As a test I have visited the MP3 url in my browser and it responds immediately i.e. there is no apparent delay introduced by our server that serves the files.  Can anyone explain why this might be happening?  This is a trial account, so I thought that maybe Twilio introduces an intentional delay on trial accounts, but I can't find any reference to that in the docs.  Thanks.

Comment: I would contact Twilio support on this one. I know that I have several voice mail systems set up and there is no delay for the audio to start playing

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, but I've got an upgraded account with credit.  So I doubt it's got anything to do with that.  Have you found out any more info about why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.  I had mistakenly specified finishOnKey instead of numDigits, which screwed things up.